# Binary categorization of entities based their properties

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm more or less looking for the right phrases to further dive into this topic. The problem at hand is pretty simple:

I've got entities that all carry a big set of properties. Those properties are not unified and  consist of ordinal numbers, non-ordinal numbers as well as strings. I can assure that for one property the value on each entity is from the same "data type".

I now want to build something that takes a bunch of old entities with their properties and a binary flag (was accepted, was not accepted) to train some sort of classifier.

After that I would love to present that classifier with an entity and it's properties to finally get a *score* back how likely it is that for that entity the flag will be set.

What am I looking for? :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are looking for a classifier. Nothing special about the task itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a Classification Machine-Learning problem and a good approach would be the [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) algorithm.